# How to apply grepl to match values in multiple columns across a data frame?

Tags: r, sapply, grepl

I would like to check if a string in one column in my data frame is found within the string in another column. I am able to do this for individual rows correctly, but when I apply it across the whole data frame the results for some rows are not correct.

Example data `df`:

```
col1   col2
XYZ    XYZXYZ
ABC    BCABCA
XX     XYXY
```

I used the following code to pattern match for individual rows:

```
grepl(df[1,1], df[1,2], fixed = TRUE)
```

I use the following code to apply across the data frame:

```
df$col3 <- sapply(df$col1, grepl, df$col2)
```

Column 3 in this case should be: `TRUE`, `TRUE`, `FALSE`.

Comment: Can you provide what result you are expecting to come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mapply`, which applies `grepl` to the first elements of each `col1`, `col2`.

```
df$col3 <- mapply(grepl, df$col1, df$col2)
df
#   col1   col2  col3
# 1  XYZ XYZXYZ  TRUE
# 2  ABC BCABCA  TRUE
# 3   XX   XYXY FALSE
```

Comment: This gives me the correct output expected, thank you

Answer (score 2):

`grepl` is not vectorized for `pattern`s.  We can use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(df$col2, df$col1)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This still gives me incorrect results when I manually check them

Comment: @sf1  Your expected is `Column 3 in this case should be: TRUE, TRUE, FALSE.` and this is giving that output